# LINQPad 4 doesn't know about HttpUtililty - how to resolve?

Tags: linqpad

I recently started using [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/CodeSnippetIDE.aspx) to test bits and pieces and its a great time saver.

However, sometimes it gives me some errors with minor things.

when I want to test this:

```
HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode("Make sure");
```

I get this error: `The name 'HttpUtility' does not exist in the current context`.

Is there a way to get it to recognize basic stuff like HttpUtility?

---

I just tried writing:

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode("Make sure")
```

and I am shown this: `The type or namespace name 'HttpUtility' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web'`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need to a reference **System.Web.dll**. Press F4 (References) and add a reference to that DLL.

Or, if you have an autocompletion license, just type your original query:

```
HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode("Make sure");
```

and open the smart-tag that automatically appears. It will present a menu option to add the reference to System.Web.dll and import the System.Web namespace in a one-fell-click!

Comment: You can find the DLL at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5`